# Symfony form rendering CollectionType without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 3.3 and want to create a form with the CollectionType. Just configured everything as written [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/form_collections.html) and works fine.

Now I want to render only one set of collection type (referring to the example, it would be one "tag", but without JavaScript/jQuery/Prototype. Still tried with

`{{ form_start(form) }} 
{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype.name)|e }}
{{ form_end(form) }}`

or

`{{ form_start(form) }} 
{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype.name)|raw }}
{{ form_end(form) }}`

which returns the form field, but after submitting is not handled (no verification is done, the "value" is lost. 
Also added `replace({'__name__': '1'})`, which doesn't change the result.

I want to create a payment process where the user has to enter only one "billing address" (would refer to "tag" in example). The essential functions in the payment process have to work without JavaScript, to make sure the user can pay even when JavaScript is disabled for no matter what reason.

How could I render one "tag" set of form fields without using JavaScript?

Thanks and best!

Entity/User:

```
class User extends EntitySuperclass implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     *
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096,groups={"account_complete","account_password","user"})
     * @Assert\Length(min = 8,groups={"account_complete","account_password","user"}, minMessage="user.password_length")
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
     * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_register","user"})
     * @Assert\Email(
     *      groups = {"account_register", "account","user"},
     *      strict = true,
     *      checkMX = true
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $emailNew = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salutation")
     * 
     */
    private $salutation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_complete","user"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9 ]+$/",groups={"account_complete","user"}, message="user.first_name.regex")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_complete","user"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9 ]+$/",groups={"account_complete","user"}, message="user.last_name.regex")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_confirmed", type="boolean")
     */
    private $emailConfirmed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $shibbolethState = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $shibbolethHash = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $shibbolethPersistentId = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_UserGroup",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $userGroups;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $confirmationEmailSend;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lastLogin = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $expires = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sessionId = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BankDetails", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_BankDetails",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bank_details_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $bankDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_BillingAddress",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="billing_address_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = 1,
     *      minMessage = "user.billing_addresses.min",
     *      groups={"test"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $billingAddresses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->confirmationEmailSend = 0;
        $this->userGroups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bankDetails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->billingAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $currentTimestamp = time();

        if($this->getConfirmationEmailSend() == NULL)
            $this->setConfirmationEmailSend(0);

   }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        //return $this->username;
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt algorithm doesn't require a separate salt.
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = array();
        $userGroups = $this->getUserGroups();
        if(!empty($userGroups)) {
            foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
                $role = $userGroup->getRole();
                $roles[] = 'ROLE_'.strtoupper($role);
            }
        }
        return $roles;
    }

    public function isGranted($role)
    {
        return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Add userGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addUserGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup)
    {
        $this->userGroups[] = $userGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup
     */
    public function removeUserGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup)
    {
        $this->userGroups->removeElement($userGroup);
    }

    /**
     * Get userGroups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUserGroups()
    {
        return $this->userGroups;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @param string $shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethPersistentId($shibbolethPersistentId)
    {
        $this->shibbolethPersistentId = $shibbolethPersistentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShibbolethPersistentId()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethPersistentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailConfirmed
     *
     * @param boolean $emailConfirmed
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailConfirmed($emailConfirmed)
    {
        $this->emailConfirmed = $emailConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailConfirmed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getEmailConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->emailConfirmed;
    }

    public function removeAllUserGroups() {
        $userGroups = $this->getUserGroups();
        foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
           $this->removeUserGroup($userGroup);
        }
    }

    public function hasUserGroup($userGroupId) {
        foreach($this->getUserGroups() as $userGroup) {
            if($userGroup->getId() == $userGroupId)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastLogin
     *
     * @param integer $lastLogin
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastLogin($lastLogin)
    {
        $this->lastLogin = $lastLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastLogin
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLastLogin()
    {
        return $this->lastLogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @param integer $confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setConfirmationEmailSend($confirmationEmailSend)
    {
        $this->confirmationEmailSend = $confirmationEmailSend;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getConfirmationEmailSend()
    {
        return $this->confirmationEmailSend;
    }

    /**
     * Set validTill
     *
     * @param integer $validTill
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setValidTill($validTill)
    {
        $this->validTill = $validTill;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get validTill
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getValidTill()
    {
        return $this->validTill;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethValid
     *
     * @param integer $shibbolethValid
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethValid($shibbolethValid)
    {
        $this->shibbolethValid = $shibbolethValid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethValid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getShibbolethValid()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethValid;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethHash
     *
     * @param string $shibbolethHash
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethHash($shibbolethHash)
    {
        $this->shibbolethHash = $shibbolethHash;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethHash
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShibbolethHash()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethHash;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethState
     *
     * @param integer $shibbolethState
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethState($shibbolethState)
    {
        $this->shibbolethState = $shibbolethState;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethState
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getShibbolethState()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethState;
    }

    /**
     * Set expires
     *
     * @param integer $expires
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setExpires($expires)
    {
        $this->expires = $expires;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expires
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getExpires()
    {
        return $this->expires;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailNew
     *
     * @param string $emailNew
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailNew($emailNew)
    {
        $this->emailNew = $emailNew;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailNew
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailNew()
    {
        return $this->emailNew;
    }

    /**
     * Set passwordHash
     *
     * @param string $passwordHash
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPasswordHash($passwordHash)
    {
        $this->passwordHash = $passwordHash;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get passwordHash
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPasswordHash()
    {
        return $this->passwordHash;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessionId
     *
     * @param string $sessionId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSessionId($sessionId)
    {
        $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessionId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $this->sessionId;
    }

    /**
     * Set salutation
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Salutation $salutation
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalutation(\AppBundle\Entity\Salutation $salutation = null)
    {
        $this->salutation = $salutation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salutation
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Salutation
     */
    public function getSalutation()
    {
        return $this->salutation;
    }

    /**
     * Add bankDetail
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addBankDetail(\AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail)
    {
        $this->bankDetails[] = $bankDetail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bankDetail
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail
     */
    public function removeBankDetail(\AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail)
    {
        $this->bankDetails->removeElement($bankDetail);
    }

    /**
     * Get bankDetails
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBankDetails()
    {
        return $this->bankDetails;
    }

    /**
     * Add billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     */
    public function removeBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses->removeElement($billingAddress);
    }

    /**
     * Set billingAddresses
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddresses
     *
     * @return User
     * 
     */
    public function setBillingAddresses(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        if($this->billingAddresses !== NULL and $this->billingAddresses->contains($billingAddress)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->addBillingAddress($billingAddress);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get billingAddresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBillingAddresses()
    {
        return $this->billingAddresses;
    }
}
```

Entity/Address:

```
class Address extends EntitySuperclass
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"user","document_access_new_step_3"})
     */
    private $line1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $line2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"user","document_access_new_step_3"})
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"user","document_access_new_step_3"})
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"user","document_access_new_step_3"})
     */
    private $country;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->country = NULL;
    }


    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set line1
     *
     * @param string $line1
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setLine1($line1)
    {
        $this->line1 = $line1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get line1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLine1()
    {
        return $this->line1;
    }

    /**
     * Set line2
     *
     * @param string $line2
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setLine2($line2)
    {
        $this->line2 = $line2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get line2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLine2()
    {
        return $this->line2;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set postalCode
     *
     * @param string $postalCode
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setPostalCode($postalCode)
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postalCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostalCode()
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Country $country
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCountry(\AppBundle\Entity\Country $country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Country
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }
}
```

FormType\User

```
class UserFinancialTransactionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('billingAddresses', AddressType::class, array(
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
        ));
    }
}
```

FormType\Address

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $countryChoices = $options['country_choices'];
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.first_name',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.last_name',
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('line1', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.line1',
            ))
            ->add('line2', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.line2'
            ))
            ->add('city', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.city'
            ))
            ->add('postalCode', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.postal_code'
            ))
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'address.country',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Country',
                'choices' => $countryChoices,
                'choice_label' => 'shortDe',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                    return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.shortDe', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Address::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            'country_choices' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.payment.user.billingAddresses) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what do you want to achieve? Share more code? What is the reason why o don't want to use js or jQuery?

Comment: the concern isn't clear.Please share in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one element in the collection, you don't need to have a collection. Instead of using a collection type in your form use directly your form type, and change the relation to ManyToOne or OneToOne

```
$builder->add('myEntityProperty', MyNestedType::class);
```

**EDIT**

if you really need a collection, then edit your setBillingAddresses to accept a billingAddresses instance, then put it as the first element of the collection, or push it in the array

in your entity :

```
...
public function setBillingAddresses(MyBundle\BillingAddresses $billingAddress){
    if($this->billingAddresses->contains($billingAddress)){
      return false;
    }
    $this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;
    /*if this function is on the OneToMany side, or on a ManyToMany mappedBy field,
      you have to call the BillingAddresses function to set or add the current entity*/
}
```

**EDIT**

```
//User

//...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      min = 1,
 *      minMessage = "user.billing_addresses.min",
 *      groups={"test"}
 * )
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
private $billingAddresses;
//...

public function __construct()
{
    //...
    $this->billingAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
    //...
}


/**
 * Add billingAddress
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
{
    if($this->billingAddresses->contains($billingAddress)){
        return false;
    }
    $this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;
    $billingAddress->setUser($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove billingAddress
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
 */
public function removeBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
{
    $this->billingAddresses->removeElement($billingAddress);
}

/**
 * Set billingAddresses
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddresses
 *
 * @return User
 * 
 */
public function setBillingAddresses(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
{

    $this->addBillingAddress($billingAddress);
}

/**
 * Get billingAddresses
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getBillingAddresses()
{
    return $this->billingAddresses;
}
```

---

```
//Address

//...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="billingAddresses")
 */
private $user;
//...

//...
public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{

    $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Just then got an error "Could not determine access type for property "billingAddresses".", which was solved by adding a setter to "billingAddresses".

Comment: Sorry, did not work properly. Just then got an error "Could not determine access type for property "billingAddresses".", which was solved by adding a setter to "billingAddresses". But then got the error "Expected argument of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection", "AppBundle\Entity\Address" given". Which is because now "billingAddresses" cloud not have many "billingAddresses". What could I do?

Comment: if you really need a collection, then edit your setBillingAddresses to accept a billingAddress instance, then put it as the first element of the collection, or push it in the array. I'll put it in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Now there is no error, but a problem with form validation. So I got an error of all the fields of "[billingAddress][0]fields" which should be validated, but the form fields which are returned "[billingAddresses]fields" are not validated.

Comment: Now I refreshed cache and now the validation of billingAddresses is not working anymore. The form fields are totally ignored, even if I add values, I got not billingAddress and also no validation. I still have @Assert\Valid added.

Comment: If your entity has been created but you don't have any address, it's because you didn't call the other side set method from the setBillingAddresses function, I told you in the comment on the bottom of the function. IF for example your entity name is client, then on the bottom of the setBillingAddresses function you have to put this $billingAddress->setClient($this).

Comment: If you need more helps you have to put at least your entities php code

Comment: Sorry I understand this comment that I can replace `$this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;` by `$this->addBillingAddress = $billingAddress;`. My entity name is "user", so I added `$billingAddress->setUser($this);`, but billingAddress does not have a "user" property. Added the entity user and address.

Comment: Sorry, `$this->addBillingAddress = $billingAddress` is replaced by `$this->addBillingAddress($billingAddress);`. Then I got again the same problem as mentioned above: In symfony profiler I got correct form errors for "user.billingAddresses[0]." all entities of address which should be validated. But the fields which are rendered are ignored by validation, so no error is shown by them. Do I maybe have to change the getter of billingAddresses to get only the first "[0]" billingAddress which is returned to form?

Comment: Now I added code data above. Do you need more information?

Comment: If you want one user to have multiple address change the relation to OneToMany, and regenerate the entitiy's setters and getters. Add a property $user in Address entity and put it in ManyToOne to User entity. Then edit the addAddresses as I told you before and test it

Comment: The property billingAddresses should be ManyToMany and not ManyToOne because the user can add more billingAddresses later (another form). Only in this form the user is allowed to add only one billingAddress, but without javascript.

Comment: if you want one user to have only one address then put a OneToOne relation from both sides, regenerate the getters and setters, and simply add the $address->setUser($this) in setAddress function in User entity

Comment: ok, one to many it's one user multiple address. With the ManyToMany you can add one address for multiple users too, but I don't think that is what you want. OneToMany it's the better way in your case

Comment: I want to have only one billingAddress in this form, but in another form there could be more than one billingAddress.

Comment: ok, I understand, it's OneToMany, not ManyToMany. You don't need one address have multiple users, just user have multiple address

Comment: Ok than OneToMany, I will change it and test it. Thank you!

Comment: But which FormType should I than use 1. in the form where user can add only one address, 2. where the user can add multiple addresses? (1. my own AddressType?, 2. CollectionType)?

Comment: you have to use two form types, or pass $options to form to load a property instead another

Comment: AddressType for your form wich needs only one address, CollectionType when you need to add multiple address. Put an if condition on an option wich have to be passed to the form from the controller

Comment: Changed the relation, but still the same problem with validation (see above).

Comment: Did you add the Many To One in the Address entity which refers to User?

Comment: The One to Many is not the owner of the relationship, you have to create the Many To One in the inversed side entity, in your case Address.

Comment: Also you have to generate the getters and setters in Address for the new property, then from addBillingAddresses you have to call the generated setUser function of Address

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is the config I still used, but does not solve the issue. Sorry! More ideas?